# OpenGL ES "imperfection"

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, glkit

I'm drawing a sort of frame in 2D with OpenGL ES. And this is the result I get.

[image]

If you see it with attention, you might notice that some borders are thicker than others.
But I specified the same width for the borders, and I'm 100% sure the camera is perpendicular to the 2D plan.
What might the problem be?

(I'm writing this in Swift, iPhone 6 with iOS 9, no GLKit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess your lines are not hitting the center of a pixel, and/or are not exact pixel multiples in widths, so you're getting noisy coverage of sample points when the lines are getting rasterized.